# How to generate Json for jsTree

Tags: jquery

i found yesterday the jsTree plugin, it's great. Have sombody a SQL sample to create the json for it?

Answer (score 2):

The SQL involved would depend entirely on your application, its database schema, and the language you are coding in. There's no general solution, especially at such a low level as SQL.